# Set View.GONE to View.VISIBLE doesn't work until get response from service , even though View.Gone is before sending the request

Tags: android, animation, scrollview

This is my mainLayout ,On click btnStart I'm trying to set up the scrollView like gone and then linearLoading visible.

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.apurata.apurataapplication.Activity.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/parentMainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetDni"
            android:text="@string/takePicture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgViewGetDni"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />

           <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetSign"
            android:text="@string/takePicture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgViewGetSign"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
           <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/listOptions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/lblVerificationCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlLoading"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/txtLoading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cargando"
            android:layout_weight="0.59" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/avi"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:indicatorName="PacmanIndicator"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/green_A700"
            style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView.Large"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is where I'm changing the visibility's status.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnGetDni:
            /*some validation*/
            break;
        case R.id.btnGetSign:
            /*some validation*/
            break;

        case R.id.btnStart :
            scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startAnim();
            /*some validations*/
            if (something is wrong){
                scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stopAnim();
             }else{
                if(something is wrong ){
                    scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stopAnim();

                }else{
                    if (something is wrong){
                        scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stopAnim();
                    }else{
                        if (something is wrong){
                           scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           stopAnim();
                            }else{
                            if (something is wrong){
                                scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                              linearLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stopAnim();
                         }else{
                               insert();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
        default :

            break;
    }
}
```

Inside insert() I'm making a request with retrofit. The main problem is the animation starts after get response from service.
 Here is the method insert()

```
     private void insert() {
     final LendService lendService = LendRetroFitUtils.getLendService();
     /*collecting*/
     Item item = new Item();
     item.setUserID(idFacebook);
    item.setSignedPaperPhoto(nuevoDNI);
    item.setDniPhoto(newSign);
    item.setCel_brand(brandCellphone);
    item.setCel_model(modelCellphone);
    item.setAndroid_version(versionCellphone);
    .
    .
    .
    /*getting information*/

    List<GpsList> listGpsList = new ArrayList<>();

    lendService.insertUsers(item).enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
        Gson gson= new Gson() ;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Item> call, Response<Item> response) {
            Log.i("Response Code", ""+ response.code());

            switch (response.code() ){
                case 404:
                    stopTransition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario incorrecto en Facebook",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 403 :
                   stopTransition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El número pin es incorrecto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 418 :
                    stopTransition();

                    Intent openBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("/*url*/"));
                    startActivity(openBrowser);
                    break;
                case 422:
                    stopTransition();
                    String errorBodyRaw = null;
                    try {
                        errorBodyRaw = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String body = errorBodyRaw.substring(0,errorBodyRaw.length());
                    Log.i(" LOG ::::::", "body"+body+"n");
                    JsonObject jsonObjectParsed=  new JsonParser().parse(errorBodyRaw).getAsJsonObject();

                    ResponseErrorItem obj= gson.fromJson(jsonObjectParsed,ResponseErrorItem.class);

                    if (obj.getStatus() != null){
                        /*some validations on error*/
                    }
                    break;
                case 500:
                    stopTransition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default :
                    stopTransition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Item> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("onFailure",""+call);
            Log.i("onFailure",""+t);
           stopTransition();
            Log.e("Main Activity", "Unable to submit post to API.");
            if (call.isCanceled()){
                Log.e("Main Activity", "request was aborted");
            }else {
                Log.e("Main Activity", "Unable to submit post to API.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

startAnim() and stopAnim()

```
 void startAnim(){
    avi.show();
    // or avi.smoothToShow();
}

void stopAnim(){
    avi.hide();
    // or avi.smoothToHide();
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what's inside `startAnim()` and `insert()`?

Comment: call your `insert();` function from new thread may be helpful.